# Accessing items in a list in AppleScript?

Tags: json, api, applescript

I'm trying to access items in a list via AppleScript. Try as I might, I can't seem to access them. I've pasted my code below

```
tell application "JSON Helper"
    set result to fetch JSON from "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&pageSize=1&apiKey=X"
    set news to title of articles of result
end tell

set result_string to news & ""
```

Note, I've removed my api key. The api format is :

```
{"status":"ok","totalResults":10,"articles":[{"source":{"id":"bbc-news","name":"BBC News"},"author":"BBC News","title":"Trump urges Israeli 'care' on settlements","description":"The US president also casts doubt on whether the Palestinians or Israel are ready to talk peace.","url":"http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-43025705","urlToImage":"https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/165CD/production/_99979519_044058382.jpg","publishedAt":"2018-02-11T16:47:27Z"}]}
```

I'm trying to access title but I keep getting "can't get title". 
Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample JSON data you gave, I used this command:

```
tell application "JSON Helper" to read JSON from ¬
    "{
        \"status\": \"ok\",
        \"totalResults\": 10,
        \"articles\": [
            {
                \"source\": {
                    \"id\": \"bbc-news\",
                    \"name\": \"BBC News\"
                },
                \"author\": \"BBC News\",
                \"title\": \"Trump urges Israeli 'care' on settlements\",
                \"description\": \"The US president also casts doubt on whether the Palestinians or Israel are ready to talk peace.\",
                \"url\": \"http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-43025705\",
                \"urlToImage\": \"https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/165CD/production/_99979519_044058382.jpg\",
                \"publishedAt\": \"2018-02-11T16:47:27Z\"
            }
        ]
    }"
```

to retrieve an AppleScript record.  Pretty-printing it as I have above, however, you might already be able to see that `articles` is a list (containing one item).  Therefore, whilst this:

```
    set news to title of articles of result
```

produces an error, this:

```
    set news to title of item 1 of articles of result
```

retrieves the correct datum.

Comment: Did that help you with what you needed ?  Is there anything you need clarifying ?